# Need Help on Making This Faster

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help on re-writing the following query to make it faster.  Ultimately, what I want is a single line per server (caption) with the corresponding metrics.  If I remove the Max and Avgs, I get 1600 line per server and runs in 3 seconds.  If I add them in, it takes about 3 minutes to calculate the data for a single server.  The total count of servers is over 11K.

```
SELECT        
   Nodes.Caption, COUNT(DISTINCT CPUMultiLoad_Detail.CPUIndex) AS CPUCount,
   Max(CPULoad.MaxLoad) as MaxCPU, Avg(CPULoad.AvgLoad) as AvgCPU,
   Round((CPULoad.TotalMemory / 1073741824),0) as MemCount,
   Round(Max(CPULoad.MaxMemoryUsed / CPULoad.TotalMemory * 100),2) as MaxMem,
   Round(Avg(CPULoad.AvgPercentMemoryUsed),2) as AvgMem
FROM 
   Nodes 
INNER JOIN
   CPUMultiLoad_Detail ON Nodes.NodeID = CPUMultiLoad_Detail.NodeID 
INNER JOIN
   CPULoad ON Nodes.NodeID = CPULoad.NodeID
WHERE CPULoad.Datetime >= DATEADD(month,datediff(month,0,getdate())-1,0)
        and CPULoad.Datetime < DATEADD(day,datediff(day,0,getdate()),1) 
GROUP BY Nodes.Caption, CPULoad.TotalMemory
```

Comment: show the table layout and the index and pk and whether you are allowed to add/modify existing Indexes

Comment: Can you also post the actual execution plan?

Comment: did you intend to have an aggregate function (SUM?) around cpuLoad.totalMemory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if this will help, don't have data to test with, but you could try pushing down your aggregate functions to where they're needed and then formatting the results:

```
SELECT      
    n.nodeid,
    Caption, 
    count_cpuIndex AS CPUCount,
    max_maxLoad AS MaxCPU, 
    avg_avgLoad AS AvgCPU,
    ROUND((TotalMemory / 1073741824),0) AS MemCount,
    ROUND(max_maxMemoryUsedPct * 100, 2) AS MaxMem,
    ROUND(avg_avgPercentMemoryUsed, 2) AS AvgMem
FROM 
   (SELECT
        caption, 
        nodeid
    FROM
        Nodes) n INNER JOIN
   (SELECT
        nodeid,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CPUIndex) AS count_cpuIndex
   FROM
        CPUMultiLoad_Detail 
  GROUP BY 
    nodeid) d ON 
   n.NodeID = d.NodeID INNER JOIN
   (SELECT
       nodeid,
       TotalMemory,
       MAX(MaxLoad) AS max_maxLoad, 
       AVG(AvgLoad) AS avg_avgLoad,
       MAX(MaxMemoryUsed / TotalMemory ) AS max_maxMemoryUsedPct,
       AVG(AvgPercentMemoryUsed) AS avg_avgPercentMemoryUsed
   FROM
        CPULoad
   WHERE
        Datetime >= DATEADD(MONTH,datediff(MONTH,0,getdate())-1,0)        AND 
        Datetime < DATEADD(DAY,datediff(DAY,0,getdate()),1) 
   GROUP BY 
    nodeid,
    TotalMemory) l ON 
   n.NodeID = l.NodeID
```

another thing this approach does is help you identify where the problem is because you can run each subquery with and without joins separately.

HTH

Comment: You my friend are a genius.  The entire query ran in 12 seconds, pulling back all 11.5K rows of data.